# moving bits from different ports and storing it in memory

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I have this question, I got a dipswitch like a selector for different modes within my application. there are 3 bits to create the selector, but they are from different ports for example, the bit number 3 from portB, the bit number 1 from portC and the bit number 3 from portC, I want to move those 3 bits and storaged them in a register so that way I can create the selector, I already did it in assembler but i'm new into C programming, and till now the only similar answer was to move all the information from the entire port but anything related to a single bit. What's the command that I should use to move those bits from different ports?

Comment: What microcontroller are you using?

Comment: I'm using the PIC18f4550 from microchip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, to get bit-level precision, you will need to use [bitwise operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C). For example, let's say you have an 8 bit container (which is also the smallest data type in C), but you're only interested in 1 bit; the best way to extract that bit would be to do a bitwise AND. In C, the bitwise AND is performed like this:

```
char c = 0x0B;
char bit = 0;

// Let's get the value of the second bit, so we must shift
// our bits to the right by one, then perform a bitwise AND
// to invalidate all other bits except the first.
bit = (c >> 1) & 0x01;
```

In binary, it would look like this:

```
00001011

Shift right once:
00000101

AND:
00000101 & 000000001

Yields: 000000001
```

To store different bits in the same memory location, you can use the bitwise-OR operator, which is the vertical pipe in C `|`. Here's an example:

```
char c = 0x00;
c = c | 0x01; /* c will now yield 0x01 */
c = c | 0xF0; /* c will now yield 0xF1 */

Final binary result: 11110001
```

With `&` and `|`, you can do some powerful things that are included in a lot of libraries to pass multiple options in one parameter. With 8 bits, you can store 8 different flags (or options), with 16 bits, 16 options. You could use this philosophy for your different ports. If you only have 4 bits worth of data in each port, you could use a 16-bit container, with 4 bits left that could simply be ignored. You'd do it like this:

```
short port_values = 0;

port_values = port_values | (port_a & 0x000F); // pretend port_a only has 4 bits of data and contains 0x0001
// port_values is now 0000 0000 0000 0001
// prepare to receive port_b by shifting the bits 4 to the left
port_values = port_values << 4;
// port_values is now 0000 0000 0001 0000
port_values = port_values | (port_b & 0x000F); // pretend port_b only has 4 bits of data and contains 0x000F
// port_values is now 0000 0000 0001 1111
// prepare to receive port_b by shifting the bits 4 to the left
port_values = port_values << 4;
// port_values is now 0000 0001 1111 0000
port_values = port_values | (port_c & 0x000F); // pretend port_c only has 4 bits of data and contains 0x0002
// port_values is now 0000 0001 1111 0010
```

Comment: thank you, it was very clear your explanation and too much useful, now i think I can take the value of "port_values" to use it in a switch sentence. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I decide to do the following code, but when i'm running the the code it doesn't enter into the switch-case just retur after to set the last bit of "COMBINACION" what could be my error. i'm new is this world of C thanks for your time and consideration.

```
 void SECUENCIA_1();
 void SECUENCIA_2();
 void SECUENCIA_3();
 void SECUENCIA_4();
 void SECUENCIA_5();
 void SECUENCIA_6();
 void SECUENCIA_ERROR();
 void SALIDA_OK();
 int i;
 unsigned char COMBINACION;

 void main(void) {
 ADCON1 = 0x0F;
 PORTA  = 0x00;
 TRISA  = 0b00000;
 PORTC  = 0x00;
 TRISC  = 0b11100000;
 PORTD  = 0x00;
 TRISD  = 0b110000;
 PORTE  = 0x00;
 TRISE  = 0b000;
 PORTB  = 0x00;
 TRISB  = 0b11111111; 


COMBINACION = 0x00;
COMBINACION = COMBINACION | (PORTCbits.RC5);
COMBINACION = COMBINACION << 1;
COMBINACION = COMBINACION | (PORTCbits.RC4);
COMBINACION = COMBINACION << 1;
COMBINACION = COMBINACION | (PORTDbits.RD3);


switch (COMBINACION)
    {
    case 0x0: SECUENCIA_ERROR; break;
    case 0x1: SECUENCIA_1; break;
    case 0x2: SECUENCIA_2; break;
    case 0x3: SECUENCIA_3; break;
    case 0x4: SECUENCIA_4; break;
    case 0x5: SECUENCIA_5; break;
    case 0x6: SECUENCIA_6; break;
    default:SECUENCIA_ERROR;
    }
```

}